# Flux / Redux: Why the term "Store"? Is there a better alternative?

Tags: store, redux, flux

Ever since I've learned about Flux and its implementations / 'flavors', such as Redux, the word "Store" has left me unsatisfied. In my opinion a "Store" is something very different from what Flux makes of it.

Actually, when I searched SO for the tag "[store](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/store/info)", it brought up the following:

> A store is a data repository of a set of integrated objects. These objects are modeled using classes defined in database schemas. Data store includes not only data repositories like databases, it is a more general concept that includes also flat files that can store data.

I know this definition is for something not JavaScript related, but it sounds logical to me and comes closer to how I understand a "Store": a component that, in some form, manages the storage of data.

In Flux (and Redux), a Store manages State, which is an arbitrary collection of values / objects. Both libraries contain the notion of Actions, objects that describe the operations that need to be performed. A Flux Store receives Actions by subscribing to a Dispatcher, with the Action handlers containing the logic to change the State. A Redux Store contains a `dispatch(action)` method, which accepts an Action object that is passed to the assigned Reducer, which in turn contains the logic the modify the state. In both cases, when an Action changes the State, the Store will notify interested parties (e.g. view components) of this change. Optionally, Action Creators can be used to make "dispatching" Actions more comfortable and less error-prone.

(I know I have skipped some details and nuances in the above description, but that's not my point here.)

So, the Flux / Redux Store has multiple purposes:

1. 'Action Router': Forward the received Action to the corresponding 'handler' / 'reducer'.
2. 'Action Applier': Apply the result of an Action to the State.
3. 'State Observer': Notify interested parties of State changes.

In none of these cases do I see the notion of managing data *storage*. Then why the word "Store"? What is it actually 'storing'?

I'm very interested in what you think would be a good alternative. If you would be creating this library yourself right now, what would be the best way to name this component?

Thanks a lot for your thoughts!

Abel

Answer (score 0):

> What is it actually 'storing'?

The "store(s)" represents the state of the UI of the application. If you think of it as a single immutable data structure with listeners, like in Redux, then the term "store" makes sense for me.

Checkout the nice Redux documentation for more details http://redux.js.org/docs/introduction/ThreePrinciples.html